# Java: Basic Spring Security MSSQL membership system needed

Tags: java, spring-security

I am looking for an implementation of spring security with MSSQL for authorization/authentication for Java. I have seen some tutorials here and there, but I fear that figuring it all out would take more time than I have for this. Is there somewhere I can download some working source code? I'm hoping I can just copy and paste the entities, xml files etc and rename the packages. Does anyone know where I can find such a basic implementation for download?

**EDIT**
I'm told Spring Security is best, but it doesn't have to be Spring.. just something that works..

Comment: Do you want to do anything special? If not you should only need to configure a datasource that points to your mssql database and setup a `jdbc-user-service` (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-providers).

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the [Spring Security book](http://springsecuritybook.com/) but I have no idea if you find the source code without buying the book (available digital). I any case I highly recommend that book. It's what taught me Spring Security.

Comment: I've published the source code to git, with updates to support Maven builds: https://github.com/pmularien/springsecuritybook - feel free to use it as you wish :)